# Adobe Animate Javascript - How to vertically center dynamic text?

Tags: javascript, flash

Adobe Animate CC
Javascript

Does anyone know how to vertically center text in a dynamic text box **in Adobe Animate when using Javascript**? Not to be confused with vertically centering text in HTML with CSS.

This doesn't work:

```
myTextBox.style.display="table-cell";
myTextBox.style.verticalAlign="middle";
```

Comment: Look at flexbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm not working with HTML.

Comment: So `myTextBox` is not HTML? and you didn't tag the question with HTML5?

Comment: myTextBox is an object on the Adobe Animate stage. I should not have tagged this with HTML5 - tag removed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your textbox is on the stage (not embedded in a MovieClip), you can vertically align a textbox by updating its y position. To do so, you must get a reference to the stage's height and divide this value by 2.

For example:

```
this.stop();

this.myTextBox.y = (stage.canvas.height) / 2;
```